# New HDD swap in SAS 6 ir shows it is missing?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, sas, raid1, seagate

**SETUP:** Dell Poweredge T410 with Windows Server 2003, SAS 6 IR Raid-1.

Both the original drives were Dell Certified Seagate Barracudas for enterprise, 250gb.

The new HDD is a Seagate Barracuda 500gb, not Dell-certified.

When I swap the failed drive with the new one, the SAS console shows that the drive status is **"missing"** -- and continues to show the primary drive from the original RAID-1 setup as the only one connected.

*Does the swapped drive need to be dell-certified to work, or am I doing something wrong?*

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes. Still says missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue today.
**My setup:** PowerEdge T100 with Windows Vista Business, SAS 6 IR Raid-1.

2 - WD Black drives 1.5TB not Dell certified, one went bad, replacement from WD is 2TB, not Dell Certified.

I plugged new drive in, it shows up as physically connected, and I can toggle it as a Hot Spare.  But there is no way to add it or tag it as a RAID drive in the array.

**Solution:** Backup the data (& verify backup), delete the existing Array, create a new Array with the 2 dissimilar sized drives, and restore from the backup.

The SAS 6/IR doesn't have the feature set of the PERC & CERC cards - see [here](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2011-February/044279.html), and [here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/PERC6/en/UG/HTML/chapterd.htm).

Good Luck!